# Novice Computer Vision Question: Identifying and Counting Overlapping Objects

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation

Good morning!

This is a very very novice question, so I apologize if this is inappropriate to ask. I just couldn't find any clear questions after scouring the net.

So essentially my goal is to count the number of pencil crayons in those old school plastic pencil boxes from grade school. However, the pencil crayons are in 2 to 3 layers so they overlap. I had initially used Yolov8 to draw bounding boxes around each of them, but I read that this might not be appropriate. Should I be segmenting out each of the pencil crayons as distinct objects and then just counting the number of unique masks SAM or some other model generates?

Thanks a million!

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkMN2.png)